# Do all equations in three variables represent a two-dimensional surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: 3d, surfaces

A single equation in the three variables $x, y$, and $z$ constitutes a single constraint on the freedom of the point $P = (x, y, z)$ to lie anywhere in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Does such a constraint guarantee that $P$ lies on a two-dimensional surface?

**Edit**

Clearly, it is possible for an equation in three variables to not represent a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$. For example, the equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 0$ represents the origin, and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = -1$ represents the empty set.

Is it possible for a single equation in three variables to impose no constraints on the freedom of a point?

Comment: What do you define as an "equation"?  $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 0$ represents only a single point, the origin.  Do you mean perhaps a *linear* equation?

Comment: Think about $(x-y)+(y-z)+(z-x)=0$ as well.

Comment: @JMoravitz By equation I meant any statement that asserts the equality of two expressions. Your example actually answers my question.

Comment: $(x^2+y^2)(x^2+z^2)(y^2+z^2)=0$ is the union of three lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you restrict what types of equations you are looking at, the answer is yes.  If you don't include such a restriction, then the answer is no.

The subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ given by $\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3~:~ax + by + cz = 0\}$ where $a,b,c$ are real numbers with at least one of them non-zero will indeed always describe a two-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ and describes a plane passing through the origin.

The sub*set* of $\Bbb R^3$ given by $\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3~:~ax+by+cz=d\}$ where at least one of $a,b,c$ is nonzero and $d$ is nonzero is a two-dimensional [affine space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) and describes a plane not passing through the origin.

If you were to consider other possible equations in forms different than $ax+by+cz=d$ then it will depend on what the equation is.  $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$ describes the origin only.  $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ describes the unit sphere, $0=0$ describes the entirety of $\Bbb R^3$, etc...